Issues with setting compiler as g++-11/14 at CLion at macos. "Test Cmake run finished with error "
I want my Clion in MacOS compile with the g++-11 instead of Clang. When I set up the toolchain, it did not pass the test. Clion gives "Test Cmake run finished with error". This is the screen shot

And I can click "more" to check the errors.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc-11
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc-11 - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/local/bin/gcc-11"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment1/_build7996487480848918631/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Fl9cKx'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/ninja/mac/x64/ninja -v cmTC_8f62f
    [1/2] /usr/local/bin/gcc-11    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_8f62f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment1/_build7996487480848918631/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Fl9cKx/testCCompiler.c
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_8f62f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o 
    /usr/local/bin/gcc-11    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_8f62f.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment1/_build7996487480848918631/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-Fl9cKx/testCCompiler.c
    clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-x86-pad-for-align=false'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) --help'
    clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '--x86-slh-loads=false'?
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Error code: 1

It looks like the test ran with some clang parameters?
ChatGPT suggested that it might be the problem with environment variable path, but it looks fine to me. Here is the output from command lines about PATH:
(base) myname@mynames-MacBook-Pro bin % which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
(base) myname@mynames-MacBook-Pro bin % which gcc-11
/usr/local/bin/gcc-11
(base) myname@mynames-MacBook-Pro bin % which gcc-14
/usr/local/bin/gcc-14
(base) myname@mynames-MacBook-Pro bin % echo $PATH
/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin:/Users/myname/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/Library/Python/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

Here is the gcc version info at my mac. Some answers suggested that gcc-11 is just an alias of clang. But according to version info, it looks like gcc-11 and gcc-14 are surely the version installed by homebrew? Sorry I am a c++ beginner and not 100% sure about this.
(base) myname@myname-MacBook-Pro bin % gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin23.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
(base) myname@myname-MacBook-Pro bin % gcc-11 --version
gcc-11 (Homebrew GCC 11.4.0) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

(base) myname@myname-MacBook-Pro bin % gcc-14 --version
gcc-14 (Homebrew GCC 14.2.0) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

An answer suggested that Uninstall gcc-11 brew remove gcc-11 and use gcc-14. I brew remove gcc@11 and set gcc-14 at Clion.here is the new screen shot.]2 The error log is basically the same:
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc-14
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc-14 - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/local/bin/gcc-14"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment/_build4029476531814106616/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-1D8OsD'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/ninja/mac/x64/ninja -v cmTC_77a76
    [1/2] /usr/local/bin/gcc-14    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_77a76.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment/_build4029476531814106616/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-1D8OsD/testCCompiler.c
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_77a76.dir/testCCompiler.c.o 
    /usr/local/bin/gcc-14    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_77a76.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /private/var/folders/lf/x7t4ln495yx9rlng8jr8yk580000gn/T/cmake_check_environment/_build4029476531814106616/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-1D8OsD/testCCompiler.c
    clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-x86-pad-for-align=false'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) --help'
    clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '--x86-slh-loads=false'?
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Error code: 1


After several editing, this question is tedious to understand now. I asked a new question here: Cannot set compiler as g++-14 at CLion at macos. "Test Cmake run finished with error "

You have not installed true GCC, you have installed gcc that is a clang alias.

Hi, I checked the version info and posted above. The GCC11 and GCC14 are installed by homebrew. I guess it means I actually installed them?

Don't use gcc-11, this is an alias of Apple clang 12. Uninstall gcc-11 brew remove gcc-11 and use gcc-14 although it does not make much sense if you can use Apple clang. I bet you got issues with the default unsupported C++11 or higher in clang and that's why you wanted to use GCC, then you should just have set explicitly a newer C++ standard in CLion.

Oh yes! Requring C++14 does not at all suggest using the compiler gcc-14, but to add -std=c++14 to the command line.

Thank you, I am really new to c++. I want to use gcc at Clion because I am taking a course and the homework is tested at linux and compiled by gcc-11. I want to develop it at my mac, thinking about making it consistent to the linux environment.

I uninstalled gcc-11 and change it to gcc-11 at toolchains setting, however, it still gave the similar errors. Maybe I should just use clang and set c++ standard explicitly. However, I am just curious about why it did not work. The Clion provided toolchains options, which means it is supposed to be able to change to gcc compiler, but why it keeps giving errors?

I uninstalled gcc-11 and change it to gcc-11 You are doing something nonsensical.

Sorry about the typo, I mean change it to gcc-14.

"similar error" is very vague issue description. Ask a new question with the verbatim error messages. Please don't edit the question here because it will make the answer not matching a edited question.
